# Complex file rename

Tags: powershell

I have some 100 files in a folder. I want to rename those files. The format of files is like

```
AB1234.gif    
B3245.gif  
AB2541.gif  
AB11422.jpg
```

and so on..

Output files shld be

```
AB-0111-1.gif
B-0111-2.gif
AB-0111-3.gif
AB-0111-4.jpg
```

Logic will be

```
for(int n=0;n<files.count;n++){
    if(file is starting with AB)
        fileName = AB + "-0111" + n;
    if(file is starting with B)
        fileName = B + "-0111" + n;
}
```

Is this thing possible with powershell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the filename format that you describe, you can use the powershell `-replace` operator to replace the middle digits with the expression that you want. The only tricky part is that you have to maintain a counter as you loop through the items. It would look like this:

```
dir | foreach -begin{$cnt = 1} -process { mv $_ ($_.Name -replace '\d+',"-0111-$cnt"); $cnt += 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension to get the extension of the file like this:

```
$ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension('AB1234.gif')
```

and you can get the first alpha characters of the file name using the `$matches` variable like this:

```
if ('AB1234.gif' -match '^\D*') { $first = $matches[0]; }
```

and you can build your new file name like this:

```
$first + '-0111-' + '1' + $ext
```

You can replace the '1' above with a variable that you can increment by checking the exists property like this:

```
$i = 1;
while (test-path ($first + '-0111-' + $i + $ext)) {$i++}
```

when this loop completes, you will have the file name you need with `$first + '-0111-' + $i + $ext` and you can use this to rename the file with `Rename-File`:

```
Rename-File 'AB1234.gif' ($first + '-0111-' + $i + $ext)
```

now, wrap all that up in a loop and you should have it:

```
dir | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

for testing, add the `-whatif` parameter to the end of the `Rename-File` command and PS will tell you what it would do instead of actually performing the action.

thanks,
mark

Comment: now that you've clarified what you are looking for, you can use the answer posted by zdan. From your original post, i thought you were looking for something more complex.